# Granting admin access rights to C drive using VB.net in Windows 10 OS

Tags: encryption, windows-10, config, vb.net-2010, admin-rights

I would like to ask for your help regarding this matter.

I have a system which contains a app.config file, which contains SQL credentials. I have already encrypted the app.config file through this code:

```
 If Not config.ConnectionStrings.SectionInformation.IsProtected Then
            config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider")

            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full, True)
        End If
```

This code works perfectly using windows 7 OS, but windows 10 is a bit different. The process of encrypting the connection strings happens when the user loads the software for the first time. My question is, how can I encrypt this document in windows 10 in a place where I cannot get access? I have to add that my default place to install this software is in the "C" drive specifically `C:\Program Files (x86)` when I check the security settings of this folder it presents to me that I do not have access to change anything in my drive, I could maybe if I force it too, but I cant do that on all PC's of the company that is running windows 10. Another option, which I think is the most simple of all, is to install the software in other drives. But this would result would cause some intervention from my part (going to another time zone that is, or maybe Team viewer can do this). I really would like my software to be a click and forget software, how can I grant admin right to my Config file from the C drive, then encrypt and save settings?

Comment: You don't grant admin access to anything. You install your configuration file in the proper location. Granting admin rights to the entire C: drive is like sending an open invitation to all malware on the planet saying *Come on in! The party's just getting started! Help yourself to all the goodies, and enjoy the open bar!*. It's no longer the 1990's. If you're going to write software, move into the right century and learn to do it properly. Per-user settings go in the user's profile in one of the sub-folders under AppData; which one to use depends on how your app uses it.

Comment: And if you've been able to write to the Program Files directory in Win7, you've been doing something to allow improper access there as well. Writing to anywhere in Program Files or the Windows directory (or the root of any drive) has been prohibited since Vista was released.

Comment: @KenWhite No, not at all, I'm not doing anything in the code, which I have posted above. Maybe, I want to give rights to the config file the most in windows 10, the problem is what I cannot because for me to grant  access rights to the config file, I have to give admin rights to the folder (please correct me I may be wrong). I get your point to, so maybe, I could give access then revert it after I have saved the changes I need in the config file? is that possible?

Comment: No, as I said before, you **do not** have to give admin rights to the folder. You need to store the config file in the proper place instead. Your code is wrong on Windows 7, because the config file is stored in the wrong place there. It's also wrong on Windows 10. See my first comment about *Per-user settings*. The only time you should be using admin rights at all is in your installer, which should be run as an admin user to allow the application to install.

Comment: @KenWhite So put the file in a different folder, with the rights that the system can alter the config file?

Comment: As I said in my first comment: *Per-user settings go in the user's profile in one of the sub-folders under AppData; which one to use depends on how your app uses it.* Yes, that would be a different folder, in the user's profile (C:\Users\YourUser), in one of the folders under AppData (a hidden folder in C:\Users\YourUser\AppData). There are several subfolders, and *which one to use depends on how your app uses it*.